# Encrypt whole root or home on Headless RPi zero

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, encryption

My question is, what possibilities are there to make your data secure on a headless Pi.
I'm pretty sure that making it disk encrypted needs an interface also with home but I want to decrypt/unlock it over ssh. Making it unaccessible physically except you have the password or unlock it with ssh.

Also how are companies like ProtonVPN or others doing it? When they buy servers on third parties, they claim that they encrypt everything so the third party can't read anything nor access it except Proton as example.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=LUKS -- https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I didn't know LUKS is available in Raspbian. Last time I checked (2014) it wasn't.